# Mathematica interoperability with Max/MSP

Tags: notebooks, interoperability, mathlink-or-wstp

A little foreword: I'm an absolute beginner of Mathematica (but I'm a programmer in other languages/software).

Now the question: I have a Mathematica Notebook written by a friend of mine which takes two input (an integer and an array of integers) and returns 2 strings (I don't think the details are relevant to my question) and he asked me to convert it in a Max/MSP plugin.
Before to port the Notebook in C (Max/MSP plugins are written in this language) I did some research about interoperability between Mathematica and other software, I found some reference for Java here: [How to integrate Mathematica with other software](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78756/how-to-integrate-mathematica-with-other-software) but for Max/MSP but for C I didn't find anything.
Somebody has some good tip on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are two different C interfaces: MathLink (lately called WSTP) and LibraryLink.  For such an application you would want MathLink.  It will allow creating a standalone shared library (plugin) that can start up a Mathematica kernel send it some input for processing and receive the output (which it then can pass to Max/MSP).  I don't know much about Max/MSP, but isn't it for real-time audio stuff?  Keep in mind that Mathematica is not particularly fast and you won't have guarantees on latency.  Also make sure that it isn't simpler to just rewrite what your friend wrote in C ...

Comment: If you are an absolute beginner in Mathematica, I'd advise not to jump into advanced stuff like this at the beginning.  It is not going to be a one-afternoon project for a beginner.  MathLink is not as well documented as the rest of Mathematica.

Comment: If you do decide to go ahead, then in addition to the documentation that ships with the latest Mathematica (and is also available online, search their site for WSTP, the new name for MathLink), do read this: http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf  Typically, with MathLink you create a separate executable that can be invoked from Mathematica, and will provide services (functions) to Mathematica.  This is called an "installable MathLink program".  This is not what you want.  Instead you need "calling Mathematica from external programs".  You won't need to use ...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: ... MathLink templates (.tm files) for this, those are for installable MathLink programs. But getting familiar with those first might help, as they're simpler.  Then you can also look at what code the `mprep` program generates from the template as it will be instructive on how to do similar things manually.

Comment: Thank you very much @Szabolcs you gave me a lot of good info to start with!  
If you rework your comments in an answer I'll gladly accept it, as suggested by Michael E2

Comment: And yes: Max/MSP can do real-time music but in this specific case it isn't needed: the Mathematica script will calculate some parameters, based on a pair of numbers, and Max will do the rest. So even if it takes some time it isn't an issue at all.

Comment: If you do not need accurate real time performance, why not have Mathematica write the two strings to a text file, and have Max read the text file? This would certainly be the simplest solution.

Comment: You can also write Max/MSP objects using Java with the mxj~ command. So you could approach it via java as well as C.

Comment: @bills thank you, I didn't knew about the mxj~ object, but still I'd prefer to have an external written in C, if I'm able to, so I don't need to rely on a second object. But I'll keep this info at hand, just in case :) I like more the idea of having Mathematica write the output to a file, if I can pass to the nb its input via command line I can simply have a little frontend in Max to call Mathematica and read the output strings. It could be even better if it is possible to have the nb to rwrite to the stdout

Comment: @kaosmos I'm not sure what is the *best* way to do it, as I haven't worked with Max/MSP.  Maybe you can go with bill's suggestion.  If you have a working solution you might want to come back and outline it in an answer.  It will be more useful than what I wrote as it will be based on actual experience implementing a solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I'm going to post my solution when I have a working and satisfying one. I did a simple frontend in max to call the nb as a shell script and it worked (with math 8+ it is possible), since the input and the output are very simple: an integer and an array of integers as input and 2 strings as output. But, in the end, we prefer to have a real max plugin so you don't need to have mathematica to make it works, the friend of mine is an electroacoustic teacher in a conservatory and she want to give this plugins to her students, I'm going to publish it on GitHub when it's done.